# What's the antiderivative of |sinc(x)|?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I need to calculate the following expression
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x|\operatorname{sinc}(t)|dt,$$
but don't know how to find the antiderivative of $|\operatorname{sinc}|$. I am not sure whether there exit an closed form for $f(x)$

Comment: Sinc doesn't even have a closed form antiderivative, so why would you expect its absolute value to??

Comment: For small $t$, $\operatorname{sinc}(t)>0$ and is entire, so you can get a power series representation (valid for small t)

Comment: From the Taylor series for $\sin x$, you can get one for this function.  Although you need to flip the sign of each coefficient at every multiple of $\pi$ (except $0$) and add a constant there to compensate.

Comment: Also, tell us which definition of sinc you use:  $\sin(x)/x$ or $\sin(\pi x)/(\pi x)$.  Of course one case can be deduced from the other.

Comment: I wonder if this is an [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info). For what purpose do you *have to calculate the following expression*?

Answer (score 2):

I get this, in terms of $\operatorname{Si}(x) := \int_0^x\frac{\sin t}{t}\;dt$ :
$$
\int_0^x \left|\frac{\sin t}{t}\right|\;dt = \operatorname{sgn}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)\;\operatorname{Si(x)} -
2\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor x/\pi \rfloor}(-1)^k \operatorname{Si}(k\pi)
$$
Here is the graph:
[image: a]

---

I did this by first asking Maple for the antiderivative. That answer was
$$
\operatorname{sgn}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)\;\operatorname{Si(x)}
$$
In fact, that has derivative $\big|\frac{\sin x}{x}\big|$ except for
integer multiples of $\pi$, where it has jumps.  So I corrected by subtracting the jumps between $0$ and $x$.

Answer (score 1):

If there was an antiderivative it would be so on (0,π/2) , But then sincx=sinx/x which is a well known function that has no antiderivative in closed form.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that $\operatorname{sinc}$ is the traditional, unnormalized function $x \mapsto \frac{\sin x}{x}$ (and $0 \mapsto 1)$, not the normalized function described by $x \mapsto \frac{\sin \pi x}{\pi x}$. Translating the below answer for the latter just requires adjusting constants appropriately.

One can't say much. By definition, $$\int_0^x \operatorname{sinc} t \,dt = \operatorname{Si}(x) := \int_0^x \frac{\sin t\,dt}{t} .$$
The function $\operatorname{Si}$ is often called the *sine integral*.

The function $\operatorname{sinc}$ is positive at $0$ and has simple roots $k \pi$, $k \in \Bbb Z \setminus \{0\}$, so for $x \geq 0$,
$$\int_0^x | \operatorname{sinc} t | \,dt = (-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{x}{\pi} \right\rfloor} \operatorname{Si}(x) + C_{\left\lfloor \frac{x}{\pi} \right\rfloor},$$ where the constants $C_k$ are determined by the condition that the quantity is continuous.

For example:

- For $x \in [0, \pi]$, $\int_0^x | \operatorname{sinc} t | \,dt = \int_0^x \operatorname{sinc} t \,dt = \operatorname{Si}(x)$ (so $C_0 = 0$).
- For $x \in [\pi, 2\pi]$, $\int_0^x | \operatorname{sinc} t | \,dt = \int_0^\pi \operatorname{sinc} t \,dt - \int_\pi^x = \operatorname{sinc} t \,dt = -\operatorname{Si}(x) + 2 \operatorname{Si}(\pi),$ so $C_1 = 2 \operatorname{Si}(\pi)$. The quantity $G' := \operatorname{Si}(\pi) \approx 1.85913\ldots$ is called the Wilbraham-Gibbs constant.

By induction we can see that
$C_k = 2 [\operatorname{Si}(\pi) - \operatorname{Si}(2 \pi) + \operatorname{Si}(3 \pi) - \cdots \pm \operatorname{Si}(k \pi)]$.
Since $\operatorname{sinc}$ is even, $\int_0^x \operatorname{sinc} t \,dt$ is odd in $x$. In summary, for $x \geq 0$ we have
$$\int_0^x |\operatorname{sinc} t| \,dt = (-1)^k \operatorname{Si}(x) - 2 \sum_{i = 1}^k (-1)^i \operatorname{Si}(\pi i) , \qquad k := \left\lfloor \frac{x}{\pi} \right\rfloor .$$

For large $x$ we have $\int_0^x |\operatorname{sinc} t| \,dt \sim \frac{2}{\pi} \log x + o(\log x) .$

Comment: how did you manage to pull a $\operatorname{sgn} (t)$ out of an integral wrt $t$?

Comment: Isn't $x \operatorname{sinc} x =\sin x$? You also made a mistake with the integration by parts, it should be $$
\int_0^x {\operatorname{sinc}t\,dt}  = \Big. {t\operatorname{sinc}t} \Big|_0^x  - \int_0^x {t\frac{{d\operatorname{sinc}t}}{{dt}}dt} 
$$ and $\frac{{d\operatorname{sinc}t}}{{dt}} \neq \frac{\sin t}{t}$.

Comment: Oops, I managed to confuse $\operatorname{sinc}$ and its antiderivative $\operatorname{Si}$!